# dnsmasq quits with "abort"

Tags: macos, homebrew, dns

I installed dnsmasq using brew, and tried to run it as a service without success. This is how I installed it:

```
brew install dnsmasq
sudo brew services start dnsmasq
```

`system.log` just shows 2 lines over and over:

```
dnsmasq[52260]: setting --bind-interfaces option because of OS limitations
com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (homebrew.mxcl.dnsmasq): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
```

I tried running it manually, and I got similar results:

```
itsadok@mpb ~$ /usr/local/sbin/dnsmasq -d --interface=lo0 --port=50003                                                                                                                              [2.2.4]
dnsmasq: started, version 2.76 cachesize 150
dnsmasq: compile time options: IPv6 GNU-getopt no-DBus no-i18n no-IDN DHCP DHCPv6 no-Lua TFTP no-conntrack no-ipset auth no-DNSSEC loop-detect no-inotify
dnsmasq: setting --bind-interfaces option because of OS limitations
dnsmasq: reading /etc/resolv.conf
dnsmasq: using nameserver 192.168.1.1#53
[1]    53009 abort      /usr/local/sbin/dnsmasq -d --interface=lo0 --port=50003
```

The exit status is 134, which is consistent with the abort message I'm seeing. Adding sudo does not help.

If I set the port number to 0, effectively disabling DNS, then the process runs indefinitely, but obviously with doing much of anything.

Any idea what's going on, or how I can debug this further?

I'm on Mac OS Sierra, 10.12.4

Comment: Just tried. It did not help. And I'm running it without a config file and still getting the `abort`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same symptoms that were described in the question as well as a new and stale PID file in `/var/run/dnsmasq.pid` every 10 seconds. I am working with dnsmasq 2.77 installed via Homebrew, and macOS 10.12.5. I had 29,000+ hosts defined in `/etc/hosts`, which was fine until some point - upgrading macOS or dnsmasq, perhaps.

I made a backup of `/etc/hosts` and then removed all lines from the hosts file except as follows.

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost

255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
```

After trying it with the minimal hosts file, I found dnsmasq working.

```
ps aux | grep dnsmasq
sudo lsof -n -i4TCP:53 | grep 'LISTEN'
```

But I didn't lose the definitions of hosts to block. They were migrated to the dnsmasq configuration file. A host definition in `/etc/hosts` looks like the following sample.

```
0.0.0.0 analytics.google.com
```

The corresponding definition in `dnsmasq.conf` looks like the following sample.

```
address=/analytics.google.com/0.0.0.0
```

Encouraged, I then added back to the hosts file all of my own definitions for my home LAN, my work LAN, some remote host nicknames, and local virtual hosts.

Answer (score 2):

Christopher's answer set me on the right path: the problem was indeed /etc/hosts.

After some trial and error I determined that dnsmasq would crash if /etc/hosts contains a domain name with more than 49 characters.

Since I didn't really want to use /etc/hosts in the first place, I was able to fix the problem by simply adding `-h` to the command line, or uncommenting the line that says `no-hosts` in `/usr/local/etc/dnsmasq.conf`

Answer (score 1):

The launch daemon is restarted because you forgot the initial step to create a dnsmasq.conf file. The conf file is referenced in the plist!

Solution:

```
sudo brew services stop dnsmasq
cp /usr/local/opt/dnsmasq/dnsmasq.conf.example /usr/local/etc/dnsmasq.conf
```

Modify the config file (e.g listening port/interfaces/domain names etc).
Then I recommend to copy and launch the launch daemon plist manually - this step has to be executed only once:

```
sudo cp /usr/local/opt/dnsmasq/homebrew.mxcl.dnsmasq.plist /Library/LaunchDaemons/
sudo launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.dnsmasq.plist
```

---

I have no explanation why the process is aborted starting it manually!